# Alterar CSS da div com clique

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Eu estou tentando criar um portfolio, a ideia dele é que ao clicar em Banner, a Logos desapareça e se clicar em Logos de novo, o mesmo re-apareça e o Banner suma. No caso, ao clicar em 1 dos botões os outros iriam sumir, adicionando a class **display_n**, que está com a propriedade *display:none*;

```css
.portfolio {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color:#090909;
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 1298px;
 padding-bottom: 100px;
 
}
.portfolio h1 {
 color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
 font-size: 90px;
 text-align: center;
 
}
.box_button_port {
 width: 200px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 float: left;
}
.box_button_port p {
 color:aliceblue;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-top:-10px;
}
.portfolio a { 
 text-decoration: none; 
}
.button_p {

 
 width: 126px;
 height: 46px;
 border: rgba(18,229,88,1.00) 1px solid;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 cursor:pointer;
 
}
.button_p:hover {
 background:rgba(11, 236, 61, 0.63);
 
 -webkit-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
 transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
}
.button_p:active {
 background: rgba(23,216,75,0.87);
}
.port_imgs {
 float: left;
 /* margin-top: -10px */
}
.display_n {
 display: none;
}
.port_logos img{
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 30px;
 /*border: rgba(18,229,88,1.00) 1px solid;
 padding: 30px;
 border-radius: 150px; */
}
.port_banners {
 float: left;
}
.port_banners img {
 max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
body {
background: #3D3D3D;
}
```

```html
<script>
$('#logo').click(function() {
    $('#port_logos').addClass('display_n');
 $('#port_banners').removeClass('display_n');
}); 
 </script>
 <button class="button_p"  id="logo">
  Logos 
  </button>
   
    
    <button class="button_p">
   Banners
  </button>
    
      <button class="button_p">
   Facebook
   </button>
      <button class="button_p">
   Outros
  </button>
   <p> clique na imagem para visualizar </p>
   </div>
   <div class="port_imgs">
   <div class="port_logos" id="port_logos"> 
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/g62Lq6K.png">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1oDuJ2n.png">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5B1bmkq.png">
    </div> <!-- fim port_logos -->
    <div class="port_banners display_n" id="port_banners">
     <img src="images/placeholder.jpg">
    </div>
   </div><!-- fim port_imgs -->
  
 </div> <!-- Fim portfolio -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta você referencia-los pela mesma classe, e com `each` verificar se `display_n` foi setado, também para ter o controle o id do botão deve ser estar contido na classe das imagens, exemplo...

```js
 $('.button_p').click(function() {

  var el = $(this).attr('id');
    
    $('.port').each(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass(el)) {
       $(this).removeClass('display_n');
      }else{
       $(this).addClass('display_n');
      }
    })
});
```

```css
.portfolio {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color:#090909;
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 1298px;
 padding-bottom: 100px;
 
}
.portfolio h1 {
 color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
 font-size: 90px;
 text-align: center;
 
}
.box_button_port {
 width: 200px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 float: left;
}
.box_button_port p {
 color:aliceblue;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-top:-10px;
}
.portfolio a { 
 text-decoration: none; 
}
.button_p {

 
 width: 126px;
 height: 46px;
 border: rgba(18,229,88,1.00) 1px solid;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 cursor:pointer;
 
}
.button_p:hover {
 background:rgba(11, 236, 61, 0.63);
 
 -webkit-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
 transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
}
.button_p:active {
 background: rgba(23,216,75,0.87);
}
.port_imgs {
 float: left;
 /* margin-top: -10px */
}
.display_n {
 display: none;
}
.port_logos img{
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 30px;
 /*border: rgba(18,229,88,1.00) 1px solid;
 padding: 30px;
 border-radius: 150px; */
}
.port_banners {
 float: left;
}
.port_banners img {
 max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
body {
background: #3D3D3D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctnOpcoes">
       
       <button class="button_p" id="logo">
        Logos 
       </button>
       <button class="button_p" id="banner">
         Banners
       </button>
       <button class="button_p">
         Facebook
       </button>
       <button class="button_p">
         Outros
       </button>
       
     </div>
     
   <p> clique na imagem para visualizar </p>

   <div class="port_imgs">
     <div class="port port_logos logo"> 
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/g62Lq6K.png">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1oDuJ2n.png">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5B1bmkq.png">
     </div> <!-- fim port_logos -->
     <div class="port port_banners display_n banner">
       <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/">
     </div>
   </div><!-- fim port_imgs -->
```